# Multiline regex replace

Tags: python, regex

I want to transform a text like:

```
$$
foo
bar
$$
```

to

```
<% tex
foo
bar
%>
```

and `$\alpha$` to `<% tex \alpha %>`.

For the single line replace, I did this:

```
re.sub(r"\$(.*)\$", r"<% tex \1 %>", text)
```

...and it works fine.

Now, I added the multiline flag to catch the multiline one:

```
re.sub(r"(?i)\$\$(.*)\$\$", r"<% tex \1 %>", text)
```

...but it returns:

```
<% tex  %>
foo
bar
<% tex  %>
```

Why? I'm sure it's something trivial, but I can't imagine what.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd suggest using the re.M (multiline) flag, and gobbling up everything not a dollar sign in your capture.

```
>>> import re
>>> t = """$$
foo
bar
$$"""
>>> re.sub(r"\$\$([^\$]+)\$\$", r"<% tex \1 %>", t, re.M)
'<% tex \nfoo\nbar\n %>'
```

Comment: This solution works--and doesn't even need the multiline flag either, since [^\$] includes linebreaks.

Comment: The multiline flag is even at the wrong position, since the third argument is `count`. If at all you should do `flag=re.M`.

Comment: Guys, `re.M` is totally redundant here since it redefines the behavior of `^` and `$` to match start/end of the *line*  rather than the whole string.

Answer (score 1):

With python 2.7.12
I have verified that this will work:

```
>>> import re
>>> t = """$$
... foo
... bar
... $$"""
>>> re.sub(r"\$\$(.*?)\$\$", r"<% tex \1 %>", t, flags=re.DOTALL)
'<% tex \nfoo\nbar\n %>'
```

As for the DOTALL flag, according to the official document:

> re.S
>
> re.DOTALL
>
> Make the '.' special character matches any character at
> all, including a newline; without this flag, '.' will match anything
> except a newline.