# Python regex substitution (multiline, only partial)

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, multiline, substitution

I searched for an answer to my question on this site. There are answered questions like:

- [Multiline regex replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102487/multiline-regex-replace)
- [matching a multiline block of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587345/regular-expression-matching-a-multiline-block-of-text)

but I'm not able to transform the information to my problem, so:

I need to replace a specific value in a text file. The file structure looks like this:

```
black
{
    part cone;
    value 20;
}
yellow
{
    part wing;
    value 30;
}
```

In a GUI the user defines the color and the new value. For example: `black = 30`. If the user starts the script, the input values are `a="black"` and `b=30`.

My piece of code:

```
dpd=open("colors","r+")
ft=dpd.read()
ft_new=re.sub(???,???,ft)
dpd.seek(0)
dpd.write(ft_new)
dpd.truncate()
dpd.close()
```

I tried something like this:

```
re.sub(str(a)+'\n.*\n.*\n.*value [0-9][0-9]?',str(a)+'\n.*\n.*\n.*?value '+str(b),ft)
```

but this does not work. I understand how to substitute a single string but I don't get how to substitute a specific value in a specific place in the file.

Comment: You need a capturing group and a replacement backreference. Something like `re.sub(r'(?m)^({}\n{{\n.*\n\s*value\s+)\d+'.format(a), r'\g<1>{}'.format(b), ft)` - see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sgh2rV/1)

Comment: thank you very much. it works. now i will try to understand it with turtorials etc. thanks again. i would like to upvote your answer but i don't get it how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
ft_new = re.sub(r'(?m)^({}\n{{\n.*\n\s*value\s+)\d+'.format(a), r'\g<1>{}'.format(b), ft)
```

The pattern will look like

```
(?m)^(black\n{\n.*\n\s*value\s+)\d+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sgh2rV/1)

**Details**

- `(?m)^` - start of the line
- `(black\n{\n.*\n\s*value\s+)` - Group 1:

  - `black` - `black`
  - `\n{\n` - newline, `{`, newline
  - `.*` - the whole line
  - `\n\s*` - newline and then 0+ whitespaces
  - `value` - a `value` substring
  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits.

The replacement, `\g<1>30`, consists of two parts:

- `\g<1>` - an unambiguous backreference to Group 1
- `30` - `30` value

Please go through the [7.2.1. Regular Expression Syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).